# phpspec - mocking return value of method

Tags: php, phpunit, phpspec

In phpspec can i mock the return value of a method?

for example:

```
class MyClass()
{
    public function getStaffMemberNames()
    {
        // db call to get array of staff member names
    }

    public function sortStaffMemberNames()
    {
        return sort($this->getStaffMemberNames());
    }
}
```

I am interested in testing the sortStaffMemberNames method.  But it relies on another class method which uses a db connection.  I want to mock the getStaffMemberNames so i can easily test.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

There's no partial mocks in phpspec (you cannot mock the class under test). This is a bad practice.

You should mock your collaborators instead (database connection for example).

Comment: Bad practice? So it's better to mock the database call in every single method that uses the method getStaffMemberNames()?

Comment: phpspec tries to enforce some practices, amongst them the Single Responsibility Principle. In your case, "sortStaffMemberNames()" has its own responsibility (sorting) and should be extracted into a new object and receive the result of "getStaffMemberNames" as a parameter.

Comment: Exactly. Whenever something is getting hard with phpspec, it indicates you've got a design issue.